# Make apps compatible to Android Tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet, android-screen-support, uses-feature

I have an android app which works fine on my Nexus . But if I upload the same app on my Samsung Galaxy Tab A, it does not do anything. I read somewhere about `<uses-feature>` and `<supports-screens>`. I worked around this, but my app still does not work on the tablet. My app uses the Back Camera and Internet. This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Can anyone tell me what else do I need to do, to make my app compatible to the tablet.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapps">

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
    android:value="barcode"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:label="Web Page">
    </activity>
</application>
```

The logcat is

```
E/BarcodeNativeHandle: Error creating remote native handle
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsu$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsu.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.vision.internal.client.zza.zzclt(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.vision.internal.client.zza.isOperational(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.client.zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector.detect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector.receiveFrame(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource$zzb.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You need to diagnose the failure. What's in the logs when it fails/doesn't work?

Comment: Are both devices using the same API level?

Comment: @revipod Yes both are on the same api level

Comment: What feature works on the phone that doesn't work on the tablet?

Comment: @revipod My app is supposed to scan a QR code, and on successful scanning open a web page in app. It does not scan the QR cod in the first place

Comment: @MattGibson - I edited my answer to add the logcat

Comment: This looks like a problem with different versions of the google play services library, check that it is up to date on your tablet.